# How to work with multiple applications with different ports/domain name in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am working with an application with below url

```
http://hostname.domain.name/login.aspx?
```

and want to work with another application which is on same server but on different port.

```
 http://hostname:8085/login.aspx?
```

I have tried setting "chromeWebSecurity": false in cypress.json but I am still getting error "CypressError: cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a second unique domain"

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.